# trying to jquery unblock a child when the parent element is blocked

Tags: jquery

trying to jquery .unblock a child when the parent element is .block[ed]. fyi, i use this for the layout and block functionality in my html and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.layout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

so, inside div "ui-layout-west", is div "lmi_accord", which holds [i want to unblock] div "current_events_div" [which gets populated during the course of page dynamically loading]:

```
<div id="ui-layout-west" class="ui-layout-west ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-west" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 977px; z-index: 0; width: 240px; display: block; visibility: visible;">

  <div id="lmi_accord" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" style="width: 100%; height: 663px;" role="tablist">

    <div id="current_events_div" class="livemihover ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 663px;" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-lmi_accord-header-0" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

then, i block ui-layout-west" [working], and try blocking current_events_div [not working]:

```
$('#ui-layout-west').block({message: null});        //working
$('#current_events_div').unblock({message: null});  //not working
```

the whole left [ui-layout-west] pane, including inside it [current_events_div] is blocked, unusable. is there a way to block the outer/parent div, then reach the inner div and unblock it? trying many things - .children, .attr, .prop, .css tricks, etc. to no avail.

latest: i tried this -  trying to set the div i want to see, its zindex to 0, then actively block it; set the zindex of the area i want to stay hidden to high, then directly block it; then unblock the one i want to see. [still not working]/ideas? ex:

```
$('#current_events_div').css('zindex', 0); 
$('#current_events_div').block({message: null}); 
$('#ui-layout-west').css('zindex', 99999); 
$('#ui-layout-west').block({message: null});
$('#current_events_div').unblock({message: null});
```

Comment: "is there a way to block the outer/parent div, then reach the inner div and unblock it" No, you can only "unblock" an element that was previously blocked. The child div was never blocked, one of it's ancestors was.

Comment: Look at it this way. The overlay covers the parent element, that contains the child element. If you block the parent element, the overlay will also block the child element. Any events that happen on the child element will be stopped at the parent. The only thing you could remotely do is change the z-index or position of the child element so that it sits above the overlay, and ensure that events are bound directly to the elements. Default behaviors will still be blocked, but custom handlers may still work.

Comment: makes sense/thx! - so then, i am trying to set the div i want to see, zindex to 0, then actively block it; set the zindex of the area i want to stay hidden to high, directly block it; then unblock the one i want to see. [still not working]/ideas? [sorry/code does not format here]:

    $('#current_events_div').css('zindex', 0);
    $('#current_events_div').block({message: null});
    $('#ui-layout-west').css('zindex', 99999);
    $('#ui-layout-west').block({message: null});
    $('#current_events_div').unblock({message: null});

Comment: you can still format comment code with `` characters

Comment: apologies, philtune but i don't know what that means; unless i can add code to this "Add Comment" section using [those] backtick chars you mentioned. tell you what, i will add that code i posted, edited back into my original post, for readability.